# How to avoid Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboard, rootview

I have 4 storyboards : Intro (Root), Loading, ChooseHouse, Home

If user logged i set Loading as root for loading data of that user like that on my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let user = getUser()
    if(user != nil) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Loading", bundle: nil)
        let loading = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = loading
    }
    return true
}
```

After user login he need to choose house and when he choose house he go to the home

N.B : i'm using `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segue, sender: self)` as modal to segue between the storyboards

The problem come when user logout and back from 'Home' to 'Intro' (i'm using also here `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("housesSegue", sender: self)` as modal, when user login the 2nd time from "LoginView" in 'Intro' storyboard i'm getting this error :

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <LoginViewController: 0x162d3a70>.
```